# Display specific string Value of JS File in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to display the first value 0.2 of Port01 in Html. The corresponding JavaScript code for this.

```
 <script>



function loadFile(filePath) {
  var result = null;
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET", filePath, false);
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      result = xmlhttp.responseText;
      return result;
    }
  };
};


var inputData = loadFile("data123.js");

 var sensorData = JSON.parse(inputData);

var valueData = sensorData[0].value;

document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = valueData;



    </script>

<body>

    <div id="value" ></div>


</body>
```

and in addition data123.js file

```
[{"name":"VVB001 (port01)","time":"2021-02-10 14:01:09","type":"a-Peak","value":0.2},{"name":"VVB001 (port02)","time":"2021-02-10 14:01:09","type":"a-Peak","value":0.2},{"name":"VVB001 (port03)","time":"2021-02-10 14:01:09","type":"a-Peak","value":0}]
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`loadFile` takes some time to fetch the data and return the data, [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) can be used to return a value later.

Here's the code rewritten with promises. I also changed the way error/success handling is done in `onreadystatechange` according to [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange).

```
<script>
    function loadFile(filePath) {
        var result = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET", filePath, true); // using true here as Chrome was complaining about deprecation of synchronous request
            xmlhttp.send();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        // promise will resolve with this result
                        resolve(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    } else {
                        // promise is rejected when error occured
                        reject(new Error('Failed to load ' + filePath));
                    }
                }
            };
        });
        return result; // return a promise (of result in a future)
    };

    loadFile("data123.js").then(function (inputData) {
        // promise was resolved and inputData is the result
        var sensorData = JSON.parse(inputData);
        var valueData = sensorData[0].value;
        document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = valueData;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        // if promise was rejected with error
        document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = 'Error: ' + error.message;
    });
</script>

<body>
    <div id="value"></div>
</body>
```

*P.S.*

[Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is more modern, powerful and flexible API than `XMLHttpRequest`, try using it instead.

*P.P.S.*

Async/await syntax can be used to simplify working with Promises. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) is a good article about that.